# Retrofit @FieldMap parameter type must be Map

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to implement a Request where I can send multiple requests at the same time using `Retrofit` so, I created an Interface like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/locations/add.json")
void sendMultipleLocations(@Query("token")String token, @FieldMap List<Map<String, String>> multipleLocations, Callback<String> callback);
```

And then, I build up the map data in a List, then push.

```
private void sendLocations(List<Map<String, String>> multipleLocations) {
    RestClient.get(this).sendMultipleLocations("token", multipleLocations, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            Log.e("MultipleLocationResp", s);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PodApi.sendMultipleLocations: @FieldMap parameter type must be Map. (parameter #2)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:107)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parameterError(RestMethodInfo.java:111)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseParameters(RestMethodInfo.java:365)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.init(RestMethodInfo.java:118)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:294)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Map, not a List of Maps. `@FieldMap Map<String, String> multipleLocations`.

Comment: I don't want to make a single request. I intend to make multiple requests with different data. That's why it's queued up

Comment: Then you have to make multiple calls of `sendMultipleLocations()`. One call of a method of a Retrofit service will always result in one http call. Use a for loop to send multiple requests.